# Jquery .load in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to load a webpage into a div using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
    $("#easyCSAT") 
    .load("https://easycsat.com/clients/?rmp=c55a4817b37ceb7af899bb761450b3dd") });
```

And then, I show the content in the div:

```
<div id="easyCSAT"></div>
```

That work in all webpage that I tested (even in different domains) but no in Wordpress, can anyone support me?

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to change my code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wordpress you can use the form:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
   $("#easyCSAT")
      .load("https://easycsat.com/clients/?rmp=c55a4817b37ceb7af899bb761450b3dd")

});
```

You can take a look to this [article](https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/)

Comment: So, if in the load webpage I have Ajax and other JS can I assume that i need to change `$(document).ready(function()` to this `jQuery(document).ready(function( $ )`?

Am I Right?

Comment: @LuisGerardoRunge Yes, this in order to avoid conflicts in wordpress.